# All divide and conquer approach use recursive functions or not necessarily?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Do all algorithms that use the divide and conquer approach use recursive functions or not necessarily?

Comment: Any recursive function can also be written non recursively by simply placing the necessary variables into a `Stack`. The divide and conquer strategy *tends* to use recursive pattern as its a very natural fit for the strategy. That doesnt mean it has to use recursion. Heck even wiki covers how stacks are used in divide and conquer inlue of recursion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms

Comment: recursion also internally uses stack only

Comment: The divide and conquer approach is not always truly recursive. The recursion might end on the first level, if the resulting parts can by solved right away without further sub-division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary search is an application of the D&C paradigm. (As follows: split in two halves and continue into the half that may contain the key.)

It can be implemented both recursively or non-recursively.

Recursion is handy when you need to keep both "halves" of a split and queue them for later processing. A common situation is called tail recursion, when you only queue one of the halves and process the other immediately. In binary search, you just drop one of the halves.

---

In a very broad sense, D&C is the father of all algorithms when stated as "break the problem into easier subproblems of the same kind". This definition also encompasses iterative solutions, often implemented without recursion.

Comment: (An alternative wording would be: _Break down the problem into easier or smaller sub-problems and combine the results of the sub-problems (and possibly some from "the border between sub-problems")_). All sub-problem results empty but one _is_ a special case.)

Comment: @greybeard: I'd prefer to go to a yet shorter statement such as "break the problem into easier subproblems", even though it drops the specifics of the (balanced) split/solve/merge process. A matter of personal taste.

Comment: More accurately, binary search is *Decrease and Conquer*.